Should someone be question-banned because of one or two users?
I regret to say, until yesterday, I had never upvoted any question posted by this learner. I upvoted many answers posted by the community but never the questions. I hasten to add, I also never downvoted. I was wrong to presume answerers would upvote the question, there is no obligation on their part, but when we have a newcomer who has bothered to read the help centre (you can tell by the quality of their posts), does the research, adds the links,  and cites their sources why would anyone willingly downvote these useful and helpful questions?
Maybe there is one reason, the learner in their eagerness to learn as much as they can,  is often guilty of posting two, sometimes three, very rarely four, questions about a piece of text, fiction and non.
I believe one or two users may be downvoting the learner's contributions, which would explain why this person is currently banned from asking questions.
The situation is plainly absurd and counter-productive, unlike most users banned from asking questions in the past,  this user has always explained their puzzlement in their questions, nearly always cited their sources, as well as shown research and commendable effort.  It explains why the user—who discovered they were question-banned on Ell—recently edited, read: self-mutilated, their posts to the bare bone, if any of you keep an eye on the main page, you know who I'm talking about.
As an example of a question, by a different poster, that shows no effort, no research and completely fails to explain why the user posted their query.

Any is fine.
Any are fine.
I have any.
I haven't any.
Are all sentences correct?

That's it. A list of examples, the question is currently on HNQ. So, we will have users outside of ELL looking at that post and thinking maybe it is a good question; it must be because it got a great answer. Then one day they post a similar low-effort question and they get annoyed and confused when comments ask them to show their research, if they looked up  the meaning(s) of "any", or to explain why they think one or more answers are correct, and so on.
BTW a thank you to @Laurel◆ for rolling back many of the drastic edits the other day.
I sincerely hope no one now starts downvoting the two users' contributions in a reaction to my meta post.

(I think some of the issue is that this user asks a lot of questions in a short span of time, which feels "spammy", even though I agree that they're high quality and usually each question is its own distinct question.)

@Kaia  Spammy? You think? Three questions a day, but sometimes only one. As far as I can tell, there's only one deleted post in the last two weeks which means the answers received were nearly always upvoted. Low quality questions tend to attract no answers or LQ ones.

Yeah, I'm not agreeing with the downvotes, I'm hypothesizing about why some people might made the snap-decision to downvote and move on. I don't think I've downvoted any of these questions.

Looking at the data available to me (both public and private), I don't see any evidence of serial voting. Even if there was serial voting, the system would reverse it overnight.
The user has about 1/3 of their questions at a positive score, 1/3 at 0, and 1/3 at negative scores. Several of these are also deleted, which can't be good. From what I heard about the ban, both negative- and zero- scoring questions count against a user, so it's also a lack of upvotes that's hurting them.
The user does have a lot going for them in that these questions aren't (or weren't) bare bones and they have a lot of them to work with. However, to get out of this, it's going to take a little effort and a bit more strategy than just deleting almost all the text (some of which still needs to be rolled back). Even small improvements could help bring these to the attention of potential upvoters.

Thank you for your answer. When you say several questions have been deleted, exactly how many? And thanks for the correction: bare bones

@Mari-LouA There's 6 that are deleted. At least one of those was an automatic deletion (score < 0, no answers)

I don't think the user is being targeted as such, but all that's needed to turn on the question ban is for one or two users to downvote as few as three questions, and any  new contributor is automatically blocked by the system. Admittedly upvotes are also  needed but those come whenever a question hits HNQ. I think the community has lost a valuable member, the learner's questions were much better than most, and as a learner their English was exceptionally good.

Serial voting would be if a user was downvoting OP in a targeted way. However, the question is whether there are a few users who downvote widely and persistently.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. The meta question asks about "one or two users" downvoting and that's what I've answered about. It's an unfortunate pattern that I've noticed even across sites that people seem to tire quickly of questions from one person about the same work or the same topic.

Now that the user has deleted their account, editing/restoring the self-mutilated posts which the OP edited in a rage, is nigh on impossible. In other words I would like to preserve the original texts, and help protect any answers that were posted. How can I do that?

@Mari-LouA You can use SEDE to find posts that aren't deleted. See Meta (this isn't the first time we've done this!) for some additional context. If you want a list of deleted posts I'd probably need to grab the list myself, but it might not be worthwhile since many are eligible for auto deletion.

I haven't the foggiest how to use SEDE. Remember I am not a programmer or a developer. I am less interested in the deleted posts, it means any answers posted were not upvoted.

@Mari-LouA The SEDE link I gave you has a working query that produces a list of question links. For me, the results are cached and show up automatically when I visit, but you may need to click a button to run the query (possibly with a CAPTCHA).

I've edited two of the remaining three posts that were hacked at by the OP. He had some good questions, and he put in a lot of effort to share his thoughts and ideas. And then three or four questions downvoted and he was suddenly blocked from asking any more.

We need to face the fact that there are problem down-voters here and on EL&U and they are killing these sites. This was a good question by Mari-Lou but, sadly, it has turned out to be too little too late. What we need is decisive action against unwelcoming, lazy, hobby-horse, serial downvoters.

Perhaps you already know this, the user recently deleted their account on EL&U and ELL. We've lost a user who had original, well-constructed questions. The one or two users who DVed the questions may not even know what the consequences have been if they never visit meta.

Or we could just face the fact that English is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. The downvoters are just following the rules as they understand them. The system was set up for questions about programming and a lot of the things that work in that context don’t work in this one. All the non-programming sites were basically accidents, so the system wasn’t designed to have the flexibility to be adapted to different site’s needs. ELL can’t even customize most of the help center.

@ColleenV I don't think there's any evidence that that's true. There are people who just like downvoting, who are online every day and downvote galore. Unlike on other SE sites, they are not shot down in flames for being incompetent downvoters. There's a competency deficit on the SE model in terms of voting. It's because of  the misguided notion of some members (on both sites) that questions must not be simple, and that because the voters are 'high level' they should downvote simple questions. It's not about English. It's about snobbery.

The guidance for when to downvote and when to upvote on SE is fine for questions about programming; it doesn’t work for ELL. From the help center “Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite” It’s not snobbery- “well-researched” is all over the help. I think you’re making bad assumptions about what is in someone else’s mind. The SE rules are very hostile to learner’s questions as written. The problem usually isn’t that people suck. It’s what they’re incentivized to do.
